# $Df(x_0)$ is nonzero $\Rightarrow $invertible. What about the reverse?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Problem says:

Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$
  is smooth and C-R
  equations

$$\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial y}
$$

$$\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x}$$

holds. Suppose that $f$
  is locally invertible at $x_{0}$
 . Show that $Df(x_{0})\neq0$
 . Find a counter-example when you don't have C-R
  equations. .

Clearly, by inverse function theorem, $\Rightarrow $ direction holds. But showing that the other direction hold under C-R equation seems to be hard since the theorem (implicit, inverse function theorem) only says about ($\Rightarrow $) direction. How could I show that the reverse holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifying $\mathbb{R}^2\simeq \mathbb{C}$. Now let $U$ be the neighbourhood of $x_0$ where $f$ is bijective. Using the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)) we can deduce that $f^{-1}$ is continous on $f(U)$. The injectivity of $f$ gives you that $f'$ is nowhere constant $0$ in $U$ and indeed, using the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) you can deduce that the set of zeros, call it $N$, of $f'$ is discret (i.e. there is a open ball around every element where $f'$ is non-vanishing). Using the inverse function theorem on $f(U)\setminus f(N)$ (note that $f(N)$ is still discret) you can deduce that $f$ is holomorphic on $f(U)\setminus f(N)$. Now use Riemanns [theorem for removable singularitys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) to deduce that $f^{-1}$ is indeed holomorphic on $f(U)$. The rule for the [derivative of the inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation) gives you that $f'$ is nonzero on $U$.

As a counterexample when C-R Relations are not available take

$$(x,y)\mapsto (x^3,y^3). $$

Comment: Is there any other way to prove it? I've never taken any complex analysis class yet.

Comment: There are other proofs, but I think they also rely on at least some complex analysis. See for example step 1 here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048204/the-inverse-of-a-bijective-holomorphic-function-is-also-holomorphic

Comment: At least I am not aware of a completely elementary way to prove it.

Comment: Thank you for your answering.:D