# Open mapping theorem for $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

It is continued from [the previous question of me](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779383/dfx-0-is-nonzero-rightarrow-invertible-what-about-the-reverse/1779528?noredirect=1#comment3632430_1779528). To show it holds for $\mathbb R^2$, I want to show the following theorem holds:

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be open and let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ be nonconstant and smooth. Then $f$ is an open mapping on $U$, that is, $f^-1$ is continuous on $f(U)$.

Let $U$ be the neighborhood of $x_0$ where $f$ is bijective. Let $w_0\in f(U)$. Then by the surjectivity of $f$, there is a $z_0\in U$ such that $f(z_0)=w_0$. Since $U$ is open, we can take $\delta>0$ so that the closed ball $B=D(z_0,d)$ is contained in $U$. Let $g(z)=f(z)-w_0$ be defined. Then $g$ is differentiable and non-constant on $U$.

Now a problem arises:

In complex case, the identity theorem holds. So, if I use it, I could show that $g(z)$ has an isolated root. However, in $\mathbb R^2$, the identity theorem seems to be false. How can I show it? Is there any other way to prove it?

Comment: Why would $f$ have to be bijective anywhere? Take $(x,y) \mapsto (x,0)$ for example.

Comment: @mrf In the previous one, it is supposed that $f$ is smooth.

Comment: The premise is that f is locally invertible, that is, there is an open set where it is bijective