# Inverse of holomorphic map on Riemann surface is holomorphic?

Tags: riemann-surfaces

Let $X,Y$ be Riemann surfaces and $f:X→Y$ is holomorphic map between $X$ and $Y$ and $f$ is bijective.

Then, could you tell me the proof of **the inverse of $f$ is holomorphic map**?

I proved this in special cases but I'm not sure where this holds in general or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The inverse of a bijective holomorphic function is also holomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048204/the-inverse-of-a-bijective-holomorphic-function-is-also-holomorphic) (The linked post concerns only when $X, Y$ are open sets, but that's exactly what you need, as holomorphicity is a local property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick $x \in X,$ and say $y = f(x).$ Let $(\phi, U)$ be a chart at $x$ in $X$ and $(\psi, V)$ a chart at $y$ in $Y.$ Then, since $f$ is holomorphic, we know that $\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ holomorphic in the typical sense, since it's domain and codomain are both open subsets of $\mathbb{C}.$ Hence, it's inverse $\phi \circ f^{-1} \circ \psi^{-1}$ is holomorphic, by standard complex analysis in the plane (since it is a composition of bijections, it is still invertible). But then, by definition of holomorphic functions on Riemann surfaces, $f^{-1}$ will be holomorphic at $y.$ Repeat for every $x \in X$ and you find $f^{-1}$ is holomorphic on all of $Y.$